# Word or term for "place of reflection"

Tags: single-word-requests

Word or term for "place of reflection"
I am looking for a better description for a place/building/location dedicated to inner peace.

Comment: Interesting question! If you have done anything to find words yourself already, it would be worth mentioning this, as you might attract some higher quality responses to your question, there are some handy tips here: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: **Fortress of Solitude, Batcave**, etc. from movies..

Comment: Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

**Retreat** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/retreat)

> *noun* 3. A quiet or secluded place in which one can rest and relax
>   *"their country retreat in Ireland"*
>   *"He wanted a quiet retreat to build his house upon and concentrate on his work."*

Answer (score 1):

**Sanctum** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanctum)

> *noun* 2. A place where one is free from intrusion.
>   *"An editor's sanctum"*
>   *"The inner sanctums of research"*
>   *"Her office was her sanctum"*